# "Expected status code in (200-299), got 404"

Tags: ios, afnetworking

This is my code:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wspublisherv2.skygiraffe.com/WSpublisherV2.svc/Authenticate"];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"john@sgdemo.com", @"UserName", @"123", @"Password", nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", parameters);
    [client postPath:nil parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"success: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"failure: %@", error);
    }];
```

It always triggers the failure block and I get the "Expected status code in (200-299), got 404" message.

When I try it through Fiddler it works.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: I know what 404 means, I just don't know how to make it work...

Comment: I would try removing `Authenticate` from the base URL and move it as the `postPath` parameter. That `Authenticate` is not part of the base URL; it's the actual page performing the request. I.e. "wspublisherv2.skygiraffe.com/WSpublisherV2.svc/Authenticate/" is different than "wspublisherv2.skygiraffe.com/WSpublisherV2.svc/Authenticate".

Comment: Going to it on my browser, it says "Method Not Allowed", I think the URL might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need more information. Use a proxy like Charles Proxy to watch the traffic between your device and the server. That'll let you see the actual request. You can compare that to a request that works, and the difference should give a pretty good idea of what's wrong. At the very least, it'll make your question much more specific.